#  PreparedStatement error 

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, ora-00918

I have two select statements and make 'union all' for these two statements. Then, I use the PreparedStatement and when I setString to this preparedStatement, it shows **"java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2".**

After I toured around google, some people say that for each "?" in sql statment, I should write setString. For my situation, I have two select statments so I have two "?" but I "union all", so I'm not sure whether it is assumed that one "?" or two "?". But when I tried to write two setString like 
**preparedStatement.setString(1,ApplicationNo);
preparedStatement.setString(2,ApplicationNo);**
, it shows **"ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined".**

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

my union select statment is

```
query.append("select TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'DD MONTH,YYYY'),a.appl_no,a.assigned_to,b.co_name,b.co_name2,a.credit_acct_no,a.credit_bank_no,a.credit_branch_no,a.service_id ");
query.append("from newappl a, newappl_hq b where b.appl_no = a.appl_no and a.appl_no=(select appl_no from newappl where appl_no=?) and rownum=1 and credit_status = 'CRPEND'");
query.append(" union all ");
query.append("select TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'DD MONTH,YYYY'),a.appl_no,a.assigned_to,c.trading_name co_name, ' ' co_name2, d.bank_acct_no  credit_acct_no, d.bank_no credit_bank_no, d.bank_branch_no credit_branch_no,a.service_id ");
query.append("from newappl a,newappl_hq b, newappl_ret c, newappl_ret_bank d where b.appl_no = a.appl_no or a.appl_no = c.appl_no and c.ret_id= d.ret_id and a.appl_no=(select appl_no from newappl_ret where appl_no=?) and rownum=1 and credit_status = 'CRPEND'");*
```

setString is **preparedStatement.setString(1,ApplicationNo);**

When I searched for setString example, there are two different parameters if there are two setString like

```
preparedStatement.setString(1,ApplicationNo);
preparedStatement.setString(2,LoginID);
```

But I need ApplicationNo for both select statments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why you should be building this query up and gc-ing it away over and over.  I'd make it a static final String once and be done with it.

If you need it twice, why can't you do this?

```
ps.setString(1, applicationNumber);
ps.setString(2, applicationNumber);
```

Comment: I have tried and it shows "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined"

Comment: Can you run that query successfully in SQL*Plus, leaving Java out of the equation?  Could be a problem with the query itself.

Comment: Personally, I think the answer from OMGPonies is better than mine.  I don't know if the SQL actually works, but there's far more details.

Answer (score 4):

I re-wrote your query as:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD MONTH,YYYY'),
       a.appl_no,
       a.assigned_to,
       b.co_name,
       b.co_name2,
       a.credit_acct_no,
       a.credit_bank_no,
       a.credit_branch_no,
       a.service_id 
  FROM newappl a
  JOIN newappl_hq b ON b.appl_no = a.appl_no
 WHERE a.appl_no = ?
   AND rownum = 1 
   AND credit_status = 'CRPEND'
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD MONTH,YYYY'),
       a.appl_no,
       a.assigned_to,
       c.trading_name, 
       ' ', 
       d.bank_acct_no, 
       d.bank_no, 
       d.bank_branch_no,
       a.service_id
  FROM newappl a
  JOIN newappl_ret c ON c.appl_no = a.appl_no
  JOIN newappl_ret_bank d ON d.ret_id = c.ret_id
 WHERE c.appl_no = ?
   AND rownum = 1 
   AND credit_status = 'CRPEND'
```

From what I can see, the [ORA-00918](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00918.php) is about the reference to the `credit_status` column.  Of the tables involved, is there a `credit_status` column in more than one of them?  Because it's the only un-aliased column in either query.

Couple other things to mention:

- don't need to TRUNC a date if you're going to TO_CHAR it for just the day/month/year info.
- don't need to alias columns in the latter part of UNION'd statements, UNIONs only need the same number of columns in the SELECT clause and that their data types match
- don't subquery for what you don't need to
- always test the query in PLSQL Developer/etc before dumping it into a Prepared Statement.  This looks like it could be a stored procedure with a single parameter (assuming the appl_no is identical for both sides)

Answer (score 0):

I also had same exception while running query in sql developer. below solution worked for me, you can also have a try.
You should rewrite the query, try and see if you can use ambiguous column table in FROM clause instead of putting it inside of JOIN expression.

Comment: Your answer is unclear; "below solution" does not refer in an unambiguous way to another answer; please, clarify other which answer you are referring.